# What is the meaning of [ ][[ ]]?

Tags: list-manipulation, sow-reap

I have a question about these two pieces of code

```
Reap[ 
   For[i = 1, i < 10, i++, Sow[i]; Sow[i^2]; Sow[i!]; Sow[N@Log@i]];
][[2, 1]] ~ Partition ~ 4
```

and

```
Reap[
   For[i = 1, i < 10, i++, Sow[{i, i^2, i!, N@Log@i}]];
][[2, 1]]
```

what is the meaning of [ ] [[ ]],I mean what does it do in the code above?

Comment: Welcome to M.SE. Please look up [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html?q=Reap) in the documentation and note in what form it gives results. Then look up [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html?q=Part).

Comment: It might help you to understand what is happening if you remove `[[2, 1]] ~Partition~ 4` in your first snippet.

Comment: `foo[][[i,j]]` is the same as `data = foo[];  data[[i,j]];`

Comment: Specifically answered in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/121) section of the omnibus.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Is there a way to export that wonderful omnibus to PDF in order to print and study it?

Comment: @Moo It's certainly possible, but I haven't done it.  There are a number of print-to-PDF drivers for Windows, some freeware, and I think Mac has that built in?  There is also some browser plugins to generate PDF's directly, e.g. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/ but I cannot provide advice on using those.

Comment: thanks of all and gwr too.